# How can I remove duplicate words for each sentence in a string?

Tags: php, string

I have the following string :

```
$string = "Russia Russia Today is my favorite TV channel.
           Boom Bust is is my favorite program on RT";
```

In the above string in the first line the word **Russia** is followed by a duplicate word and in the second line the word **is** is followed by a duplicate word.

I want to remove all the duplicate words that are followed by the similar words.
So far I have visited some similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they don't seem to help.

I tried this:

```
<?Php 

    $string = "Russia Russia Today is my favorite TV channel.Boom Bust is is my favorite program on RT";

    $arr = explode( " " , $string );
    $arr = array_unique( $arr );
    echo $string = implode(" " , $arr);
```

output:

```
Russia Today is my favorite TV channel. Boom Bust my favorite program on RT";
```

Notice the missing word **is** it is missing in the output.

My expacted output should be :

```
Russia Today is my favorite TV channel. Boom Bust is my favorite program on RT
                                                //^^
```

Comment: `Russia Today` **is** <- You already have it here once

Comment: Rizier sorry I didn't understand why it is replacing "is" in the output

Comment: your expected output also having 2 is

Comment: Because the first time you have it is here: `Russia Today is`, so all other "is" will get removed

Comment: @Rizier123 is there a way to impliment this?

Comment: The problem is `array_unique` doesn't just check the values next to each other, it makes sure there is only one instance of a value in the entire array.

Comment: @Starkeen You have to specify more, when duplicate words are allowed and when not

Comment: first explode string into array, and create new array, while insert into new array check whether already exist or not....

Comment: @Rizier123 I will rewrite this question, There are a lot of spelling error because of the fast edit, May be so I got minus.

Comment: @Starkeen you probably got a -1 for lack of effort to solve the problem yourself. As soon as you got stuck you asked here, you haven't even tried any other solution, such as writing your own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first `explode()` you string by a dot to get the single sentence. Then I explode each sentence into words. After this you can just take all unique words for each sentence and then you can print them again.

```
<?php

    $string = "Russia Russia Today is my favorite TV channel.Boom Bust is is my favorite program on RT";
    $sentence = explode(".", $string);
    $words = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(" ", $v);
    }, $sentence);

    $uniqueWords = array_map("array_unique", $words);

    foreach($uniqueWords as $v)
        echo implode(" ", $v) . ".<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
Russia Today is my favorite TV channel.
Boom Bust is my favorite program on RT.
```

**EDIT:**

If you just would want to replace multiple occurrences of words after each other, you could use this:

```
$str = "That solves the users specific issue, but it wouldn't solve something like Russia Russia Today is my favourite TV channel in Russia. ";
echo $str = preg_replace("/\b(\S+)\b(\s+\g{1}\b)+/", "$1", $str);
```

output:

```
That solves the users specific issue, but it wouldn't solve something like Russia Today is my favourite TV channel in Russia.
```

Comment: That solves the users specific issue, but it wouldn't solve something like `Russia Russia Today is my favourite TV channel in Russia.`

Comment: I tested your solution with 2 diffrent strings, it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Styphon Added a solution if OP would want to replace multiple occurrences of the same word after each other. But it seems like he doesn't want that.

Comment: Rizier, sorry to disturb you again, I need your help with something. Could you help me?

Comment: @Starkeen What is the problem ?

Comment: @Starkeen okay, I've added the rest of your output

Comment: Thank you so much Rizier ! God bless you! If you pass by Bristol please give me a missed call and I will pay you a  beer :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to write a custom function. You need to explode the string as you are doing right now, then check each value in sequence. If it's the same as the previous instance, remove it.

Something like this should do it:

```
function remove_duplicate_words($string)
{
    $arr = explode(" ", $string);
    $prev_word = '';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        // skip the first word
        if ($key == 0) 
        {
            $prev_word = $val;
            continue;
        }

        if ($prev_word == $val)
        {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $prev_word = $val;
        }
    }
    return implode(" " , $arr);
}

$string = remove_duplicate_words("Russia Russia Today is my favorite TV channel. Boom Bust is is my favorite program on RT");
```